# MVC in Angular 2 - update component from service?

Tags: model-view-controller, angular

AIM: I send a http request from angular 2 ui to java server. While it is executing, server generates messages with progress status so I can update progress bar on ui.

I have 3 entities: *AppComponent*, *AppService* and *WebsocketService*. 
Here is a simplified example of *WebsocketService*. It can subscribe to message topic and perform some actions on incoming each message.

```
export class WebsocketService {

    private client: Client;

    constructor() {
        var service = this;
        service.client = Stomp.client('ws://localhost:8080/stomp/websocket');

        service.client.connect("user", "pass", function () {
            service.client.subscribe("/progress", function (message) {
                // some actions here
            })
        });
    }
}
```

So, my question is: how to update AppComponent's property (field) value, which is binded to template, from AppService or even WebsocketService? Use a setter? Is it allright from the terms of MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this but I would use a "Subject" stream.

Here is an example:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {NextObserver} from 'rxjs/Observer';

export class WebsocketService {
    public ProcessingMessages$: Observable<string>;

    private client: Client;
    private processingMessages: Subject<string>;


    constructor() {
        this.processingMessages = new Subject<string>();
        this.ProcessingMessages$ = this.processingMessages.asObservable();

        var service = this;
        service.client = Stomp.client('ws://localhost:8080/stomp/websocket');

        service.client.connect("user", "pass", function () {
            service.client.subscribe("/progress", function (message) {
                this.processingMessages.next(message);
            })
        });
    }
}

// Sample Component
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: 'WebsocketService Message: {{Message}}',
})
export class Sample Component implements OnInit {
    public Message: string;

    constructor(
        private service: WebsocketService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.ProcessingMessages$.subscribe((message: string) => {
            this.Message = message;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about observable, but I didn't know how to publish to observables. Thanks for the good example! Can I also ask, using '$' in the end of observable, along with writing it from the capital letter, it is only your preference or it is kind of naming convention?

Comment: It's a naming convention so we know it's an observable subject stream. I got that from the Angular 2 site. You don't ab fault need to have two separate variables either, I like it better that way but you can simple crest a function in your service that returns this.processingMessage.asObservable(), and subscribe to that instead.

Comment: Didn't find any examples of using this naming convention. Could you please help me by providing some links?

Comment: Sure. Here is the official style guide. https://angular.io/styleguide. And here is where I initially saw what I'm talking about: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!%23bidirectional-service

Comment: As I see its only about '$' sign in the end, not about capital letter?

Comment: Right. The capital letters are my own thing. Capital letters for public members and small letters for private variables.